# Curret Date becomes undefined when a method is called in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, date, ionic-framework

I have displayed the current date in my page by setting the minimum and maximum date in which i have set the maximum date to be the current date.When the page is loaded it displays the current date but when i press a button to call a function the date becomes undefined.I don't know why it occurs but when i select a date using date picker and click the button it works fine can anyone tell me why the default date displayed becomes undefined when a function is called.

Html:

```
<ion-content class="p-l-10 p-r-10 had-header form_slide_page">      
<form ng-submit="vm.addExpense()">
   <div class="list">
      <label class="item item-input InputFormFull">
        <span class="input-label">{{'date_message' | translate}}</span>
        <input type="date" placeholder="Date" ng-model="vm.expense.date" min="1980-01-01" max="{{vm.today | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}">
      </label>

      <label class="item item-input InputFormFull" ng-click="vm.gotoNewCategory()">
         <span class="input-label">{{'expensename_message' | translate}}</span>
         <input placeholder="{{'expensename_message' | translate}}" 
          ng-model="vm.expense.category" ng-readonly="true" ng-change="vm.fillStarted()">
       </label>

      <label class="item item-input InputFormFull">
        <span class="input-label">{{'amount_message' | translate}}</span>
        <input type="number" step=".01" placeholder="{{'amount_message' | translate}}" ng-model="vm.expense.amount_out" ng-change="vm.fillStarted()" 
          next-focus id="field1" ng-focus="vm.scrollMe('field1')"
         field-to-validate="yes" field-value="{{vm.expense.amount_out}}" field-validation-type="num" field-name="Amount">
      </label>

      <button class="trans-but button" type="submit">{{'save_message' | translate}}</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Script:

```
function activate () {
  vm.expense = {};
  /*vm.expense.date = new Date();*/
  vm.expense.user_id = window.localStorage['user_id'];
  $log.log('vm.expense', vm.expense);
  $log.log('expense details', $stateParams.expenseDetails);
  vm.expense.category = $stateParams.expenseDetails.category;
  vm.expense.amount_out = $stateParams.expenseDetails.amount_out;
  vm.expense.date = $stateParams.expenseDetails.date;
  vm.items = []; // fix me (if needed modify to categories instead of item)
  screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
  DB.getByColVal('category', 'category', ['Expense']).then(function (result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
      vm.items.push({display: result.rows.item(i).name});
    }
    $log.log('vm.items: ', vm.items);
  }, CommonService.handleError);
  /*$scope.today = new Date().toISOString();*/
  //$scope.today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
  vm.today = new Date();
  var dd = vm.today.getDate();
  var mm = vm.today.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = vm.today.getFullYear();
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
  }
  vm.today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
  $log.log('CalendarDate', vm.today);
  localforage.setItem('categoryEnteredDetails', '');
}
```

Function which makes the default date to be undefined:

```
function gotoNewCategory () {
  vm.catgory = {};
  $log.log('Expense Details ', vm.expense);
  vm.catgory.userdetail = vm.expense; //fix me
  vm.catgory.userentry = vm.expense;
  vm.catgory.userdetail.type = 'Expense';
  vm.catgory.catergorytype = 'Expense';
  localforage.setItem('categoryType', 'Expense');
  $state.go('categoryType', {CategoryDetails: vm.catgory});
}
```

LogCat:

```
Object {user_id: "60", category: "", amount_out: 85, date: undefined}
```

Comment: Can you share the jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it happens because in your `gotoNewCategory()` you have `$state.go('categoryType', {CategoryDetails: vm.catgory})`.

So when you change state, `$stateParams` is changing too, so `vm.expense.amount_out = $stateParams.expenseDetails.amount_out` may reassign in into undefined, because `$stateParams` was changed

I believe you can try to fix it with  `$state.go('categoryType', {CategoryDetails: vm.catgory, expenseDetails: vm.expense})`